# Is there anyway to do a reverse index in Python

Tags: python

Ok I guess it did not make sense the first time I posted. But what I want to know if there is a method that does that does the opposite of what the indexing method does. For example lets say I input in python shell >>> l = 'hello' I know that if I put in the index l[2] the result will be 'l'. But what I want to know if there is any simple method I could use that if I put in l['h'] it would return 0, the indexing value/ position in the string. I need it so that I can put it into a function.

Comment: If you are trying to described an algorithm, it really helps if you show example input and output, and explain the relationship between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `index` method:

```
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> s.index('h')
0
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question properly then I think you're looking for `enumerate()`:

```
>>> for ind, char in enumerate("mystring"):
...     print ind,char
...     
0 m
1 y
2 s
3 t
4 r
5 i
6 n
7 g
```

**help** on `enumerate`:

```
>>> enumerate?
Docstring:
enumerate(iterable[, start]) -> iterator for index, value of iterable

Return an enumerate object.  iterable must be another object that supports
iteration.  The enumerate object yields pairs containing a count (from
start, which defaults to zero) and a value yielded by the iterable argument.
enumerate is useful for obtaining an indexed list:
    (0, seq[0]), (1, seq[1]), (2, seq[2]), ...
```

**Edit:**

To get the index of first match of any substring you can use `str.index` or `str.find`.

`str.index` will raise `ValueError` if the item is not found and `str.find` will return -1:

```
>>> strs = "hello"
>>> strs.index("h")
0
>>> strs.find("h")
0
>>> strs.find("m")
-1
>>> strs.index("m")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-9-5f19ab4b0632>", line 1, in <module>
    strs.index("m")
ValueError: substring not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not crystal clear - providing a set of inputs and expected outputs usually help. Anyway, if I understand correctly, what you want is something like:

```
def fun(index, bstr):
    try:
        return int(bstr[index])
    except IndexError, e:
        # should handle the error here - don't know what 
        # behaviour you expect
        raise

def encrypt(text, bstr): 
    for index, char in enumerate(text):
        flag = fun(index, bstr)
        if flag: # iow : 'if flag == 1'
           do_something()
        else: # iow : 'if flag == 0'
            do_something_else()

encrypt("allo", "0001")
```

As a side note, considering your code snippet, I think you should first learn to program in Python - the first `for` loop does nothing except eating cpu cycles, and the first line of the second creates a list that is immediatly discarded